# Removing stopwords from a large list of stop words taking forever

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am doing some NLP on a dataset and I am trying to remove stopwords.

I am not using the nltk built in stopwords and I am using a custom stopwords list (which is about 10k words in different languages)

I first defined the below function

```
def clean_text(text):
    text = ''.join([word.lower() for word in text if word not in string.punctuation])
    tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
    text = [lm.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens if word not in stopwords]
    return text
```

then I applied it to the dataframe as follows:

```
df_train['clean_text'] = df_train['question_text'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
```

My Problem is that it is taking so long to process, so is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What type of data structure is `stopwords` a list or a set?

Comment: I first used a normal list then I tried stopwords=list(set(stopwords)) and it is still taking forever

Comment: keep it at a set, should be a lot faster: `stopwords = set(stopwords)`

Comment: That actually worked, thanks man!

Comment: replacing the punctuation part with regex is another thing that improves performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contains checks (`x in data_structure`) for strings and lists are linear. That means `string.punctuation` is iterated for every single character in your initial `text` and `stopwords` is iterated for every token. Turn them both into sets to make these checks constant:

```
punct = set(string.punctuation)
stopwords = set(stopwords)

def clean_text(text):
    text = ''.join(char.lower() for char in text if char not in punct)
    tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
    text = [lm.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens if word not in stopwords]
    return text
```

Some references:

1. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set
2. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list